# Playwright C# - Handling Toast Messages

Tags: c#, playwright

Im trying to check the content of a toast message using playwright but cant find a suitable way to acheive this.

The playwright documentation lists a suitable way to handle alert messages with which I have been able to do things like retrieve the text content from an alert before dismissing it. For example:

```cs
Page.Dialog += (_, dialog) =>{
  alertMessage = dialog.Message;
  Console.WriteLine(alertMessage);
  dialog.AcceptAsync();
};
```

prints the alert text content prior to accepting the dialog. This can be extended to perform checks such as asserts etc

I've tried using the same approach when trying to handle the toast message but this doesn't work for me, presumably due to different nature of the toast message.

Has anyone successfully managed to interrogate toast messages using playwright?

There is no official documentation from playwright on how to handle toast messages.

Comment: Isn't a toast message just more elements that get loaded in to the DOM rather than being a page or a popup/alert in JS? If so, you should be able to interact with them as you would do with any other element on the page with Playwright.  That is certainly the case with the toast elements in the software I am testing.  If not, can you clarify how they appear or perhaps what framework is used to create them?

Comment: Yes thanks for your reply, I just realised that rather than trying to handle the toast like an alert, it can be treated just like any other elements on the page

Answer (score 1):

### Handling Toast Messages in Automation(JS Code):

Toast messages are normal html elements within the page(not in alert) however they are special in sense as they appear for a very short time and then disappear so we need to handle them accordingly in automation. Example Below:

```
async clickSave() {
     await Promise.all([
      this.page.waitForSelector(loadPanel),
      this.page.click(btn_Save),
      this.page.waitForSelector('div[class*="ajs-success"]',{state: 'attached'}) //Toast Success message on save successfully
     ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await _chromeDriver.Page.Locator("#toast-container.toast-bottom-right").Filter(new() {
    HasText = "something message"
}).WaitForAsync();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. –