# How to wait until the specific div gets loaded and hidden

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Adding some tests using playwright. In one of the tests, When I click on save button, new div will get added to DOM and after some time div will be hidden in the DOM when the save operation gets completed.

Now, I need to test this functionality, when I click the save button, it should auto wait until the save operation gets completed. To check if the save operation completed or not, we can check whether the div with className `helloDiv` gets added and hidden. when the div is hidden we can move forward.

I was able to click the button. But the challenge is to wait until the save operations gets completed.

Tried the following but unable to implement this. Note that my div that is getting added is inside a iframe and many div's in between the heirarchy.

```
// Click the save button
await this.saveMenu.root.click()
await this.page.waitForSelector('div.helloDiv', { state: 'visible' });
await this.page.waitForSelector('div.helloDiv', { state: 'hidden' });
```

After the button has been clicked, it was unable to detect the div being visisble and failing.

Tried adding the data-testid to the div, still the same result. The problem is if i didn't include the visible step, after button click,it will take 2-3 sec for the div to load and couple more secs to hide.

```
await this.page.getByTestId('helloDiv').waitFor();
await this.page.getByTestId('helloDiv').waitFor({state:'hidden'});
```

We don't want to use the waitForTimeout and want to implement the functionality by checking the div.
Can anyone please help me with this one

Comment: Hard to help without the site as a [mcve],

Comment: @Kotana Sai This will be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74693151/

Answer (score 0):

Could you share your DOM?

Anyway I think need to add right locators with  https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-framelocator

`await this.page.framelocator('yourIframe').getByTestId('helloDiv').waitFor();`

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the response. Although changed my approach and no longer using this, Will give a shot as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As its about handling race conditions, I think this would help:

```
async clickSaveAndVerify() {
     await Promise.all([
      this.page.waitForSelector('div.helloDiv', { state: 'visible' }),
      this.saveMenu.root.click(),
      this.page.waitForSelector('div.helloDiv', { state: 'hidden' });
     ]);
}
```